# Get filename from current image

Tags: typo3, typoscript

can anybody tell me how I can get the current image filename. I have to link the current image to open it in a lightbox.

My code:

```
15 = TEXT
    15 {
      field = image
      split {


        token = ,
        cObjNum = 1 || 3 || 3


        //ignore
        1....


        3 {
          10 = IMAGE
          10.file.import.current = 1
          10.file.import = uploads/pics/
          10.file.maxW = 270
          10.params = class="hidden"

          10.imageLinkWrap = 1
          10.imageLinkWrap {
            enable = 1
            typolink.parameter = TEXT
            typolink.parameter.field = image
            typolink.parameter.listNum.splitChar = ,

            typolink.parameter.listNum = // <- Need current image number
            typolink.parameter.wrap = /uploads/pics/|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have some special vars set during img mainpulation. From TYPO3 wiki

IMG_RESOURCE:
While rendering an img_resource TYPO3 sets TSFE:lastImgResourceInfo which is a numerical array of image information

```
TSFE:lastImgResourceInfo|0 contains the width (after scaling) of the image
TSFE:lastImgResourceInfo|1 contains the height (after scaling) of the image
TSFE:lastImgResourceInfo|2 contains the image file extension
TSFE:lastImgResourceInfo|3 contains the path to the (scaled) image file
TSFE:lastImgResourceInfo|origFile contains the name (path?) of the original file
TSFE:lastImgResourceInfo|origFile_mtime contains the the last modification time of the original file
```

So you can use them for example with data

```
10 = TEXT
10.data = TSFE:lastImgResourceInfo|3
```

Comment: Thanks anyway, but I found another solution by myself (+chef). Here is my solution:

    typolink.parameter.stdWrap.data = register : SPLIT_COUNT

Comment: Actually my answer is wrong. I read your question too fast. I though you need rescalled image name. The best would be that you make a separate answer for you question and my answer will be deleted then.

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.typo3.org/TSref/stdWrap#current
http://www.typo3wizard.com/de/snippets/general-config/bild-aus-media-feld.html

field "image"

```
lib.images=TEXT
lib.images.data= levelmedia: 2,slide
lib.images.wrap=<div id="bilder">|</div>
lib.images.split{
token=,
cObjNum=1
1.10=IMAGE
1.10.file{
 import.current=1
 import=uploads/media/
 width = 270
 height= 300
}
}
```